# How to stop leaflet from registering click on map when clicking zoom control

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, leaflet

So I am having this problem in chrome with leaflet 1.0.3. When I am drawing a polygon or line, and I try to click on the zoom buttons it will plot a point. I have set up a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/twusqzn4/3/) to show you what I am talking about.

I have tried to change the z-index but that didn't work also just edited the zoom functions to remove the last point but that created problems in firefox. I need it not to plot a point when I am trying to zoom in and out while drawing.

To recreate the problem just click on the polygon or line tool on the right to begin drawing and then click the zoom buttons.

```
dont 
mind   
these 
lines
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're suffering from Leaflet bug [#5308](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5308) - event propagation with `pointerevent`s was buggy depending on the browser.

This was addressed in Leaflet 1.1.0, so the solution to your problem is to simply upgrade.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this without upgrading? When I upgrade, it breaks a lot of my code that I don't really have the time to fix.

Comment: I was able to test it with some of my code and it works. I am still experiencing this problem with the 'topcenter' position from a plugin though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just editing the events of the zoom control, as well as a few other buttons I had up. I added the function for removing the last point to fix my problem. I had to add a browser check so that it would only remove the last point on the browsers that were giving me problems.

The better thing to do is to upgrade leaflet so it works smoother, but due to time constraints this is my solution for now.